# Lua Copas: Sender coroutine just stops working

Tags: sockets, lua, lua-5.2, copas

I have a problem using latest Copas in Lua 5.2.
I wrote a simple script (see below) which creates two server sockets: "RX" and "TX".
"RX" listens for messages from connected clients, "TX" transmits those messages to clients connected to "TX".

The problem is: In the beginning, after server start-up, everything works fine. But after a certain amount of messages, the "TX" server loop is not executed anymore, no more messages are transmitted.
There is no error message, nothing. It just stops working.

Am I using Copas wrong? What is the problem?

This is the (simplified) code:

```
local copas    = require("copas")
local socket   = require("socket")
local pl_class = require("pl.class")


-- Connection between a server and a client
pl_class.ClientConnection()

function ClientConnection:_init(connectionName, socketToClient)
    self.connectionName       = connectionName
    self.socketToClient       = socketToClient
    self.queueMessagesToSend  = {}
end

function ClientConnection:popMessageToSend()
    return table.remove(self.queueMessagesToSend, 1);
end

function ClientConnection:pushMessageToSend(theMessage)
    table.insert(self.queueMessagesToSend, theMessage)
end


-- Server base class
pl_class.Server()

function Server:_init(serverName, serverPort)
    self.serverName            = serverName
    self.serverPort            = serverPort
    self.connectedClients      = {}
end

function Server:initServing()
    local server = socket.bind("*", self.serverPort)
    print("[" .. self.serverName .. "] Waiting for client connections on port " .. self.serverPort .. "...")
    copas.addserver(server, function(c) return self.connectionHandler(copas.wrap(c), c:getpeername()) end )
end


-- Class for send-only servers
pl_class.ServerSendOnly(Server)

function ServerSendOnly:_init(serverName, serverPort)
    self:super(serverName, serverPort)

    self.connectionHandler = function (socketToClient, clientHost, clientPort)
        local connObject = ClientConnection(clientHost..":"..tostring(clientPort), socketToClient)
        self.connectedClients[connObject.connectionName] = connObject
        while true do
            local currMessage = connObject:popMessageToSend()
            if currMessage then
                copas.send(connObject.socketToClient, currMessage)
            end
            copas.sleep(0.01)
        end
        self.connectedClients[connObject.connectionName] = nil
    end

end

function ServerSendOnly:broadcastMessage(currMessage)
    for connName,connObject in pairs(self.connectedClients) do
        connObject:pushMessageToSend(currMessage .. "\r\n")
    end
end


-- Class for receive-only servers
pl_class.ServerReceiveOnly(Server)

function ServerReceiveOnly:_init(serverName, serverPort)
    self:super(serverName, serverPort)
    self.queueMessagesReceived = {}

    self.connectionHandler = function (socketToClient, clientHost, clientPort)
        local connObject = ClientConnection(clientHost..":"..tostring(clientPort), socketToClient)
        self.connectedClients[connObject.connectionName] = connObject
        while true do
            local currDataReceived = copas.receive(connObject.socketToClient)
            if currDataReceived ~= nil then
                local currInfo = {client=connObject.connectionName, data=currDataReceived}
                table.insert(self.queueMessagesReceived, currInfo)
            end
        end
        self.connectedClients[connObject.connectionName] = nil
    end

end

function ServerReceiveOnly:popMessageReceived()
    return table.remove(self.queueMessagesReceived, 1);
end


-- Setup servers
local serverSend    = ServerSendOnly("ServerTX", 2345)
local serverReceive = ServerReceiveOnly("ServerRX", 1234)

serverSend:initServing()
serverReceive:initServing()


-- Main loop: Pass messages which arrived at the RX server to the clients
-- connected to the TX servers ("RX" and "TX" are used from the server's POV)
while true do
    copas.step()

    local currMessage = serverReceive:popMessageReceived()
    if currMessage then
        print("[" .. serverReceive.serverName .. "] MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM '" .. currMessage.client .."': " .. currMessage.data)
        serverSend:broadcastMessage(currMessage.data)
    end
end
```

Comment: Which version do you mean by "latest Copas"? Is it 1_2_1, [master branch](https://github.com/keplerproject/copas) or something else? Also, it would help to have a much shorter example on which you can reproduce the problem. What data are you sending? Do you have large lines there?

Comment: Yes, Copas v1.2.1 from the master branch.

The data just consists of short strings. To test it, I connect with Telnet to both the RX and the TX server, and I just type "Hello World" and similar strings in one Telnet process and hope to receive it in the other one.

Maybe the code could be shortened if I drop the class structure, but actually I think it is easier to read this way.

Comment: "Maybe the code could be shortened if I drop the class structure, but actually I think it is easier to read this way." 

This may well be the case, but if socket/copas dependency is unavoidabe, penlight is not, so the easier it is for others to try your example, the more likelihood you get a useful response.